# Spring boot JPA with 1:M primary key null

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, rest

I have 2 entitied (Post and FileUploads), the Post entity is responsible for a user to create an advert/post and the FileUploads entity is responsible for handling image uploads together with a post. (A post can have multiple FileUploads/Images associated with it).

The issue is that I get an error:
  `Column 'post_id' cannot be null`

- I'm unsure as to what's causing it, The PK in the FileUpload entity is a String and the Post entity PK is a Long, I don't know if that could be the cause?
- I am auto-generating my Post PK as well.

---

**FileUpload.java** (Entity)

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="file_upload")
public class FileUpload {

    @Id
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @Column(name="id")
    private String fileId;

    private int imageCount;

    private String name;

    private String type;

    private String fileUploader;

    @Lob
    private byte[] data;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="post_id", nullable = false)
    private Post post;

    public FileUpload() {

    }

    public FileUpload(int imageCount, String name, String type, String fileUploader, byte[] data, Post post) {
        this.imageCount = imageCount;
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
        this.fileUploader = fileUploader;
        this.data = data;
        this.post = post;
    }
```

---

**Post.java** (Entity)

- Left out the other fields since i have a quite a bit

```java
@Entity
public class Post {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Required")
    @Size(max=45, message = "Maximum of 45 letters")
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String title;

    private String postCreatorEmail;

    private String postCreator;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "post")
    private List<FileUpload> fileUploads = new ArrayList<>();


    public Post() {
    }
```

---

**FileServiceImpl.java**

- Method to store images

```java
@Service
public class FileUploadServiceImpl implements FileUploadService{

    @Autowired
    private FileUploadRepository fileUploadRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    private int imageCount;


    @Override
    public FileUpload uploadPostImage(MultipartFile file, String emailAddress) throws IOException {
        Post thePost = postRepository.findPostByPostCreatorEmail(emailAddress);


        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
        FileUpload fileDB = new FileUpload(++imageCount, fileName, file.getContentType(), emailAddress, file.getBytes(), thePost);

        return fileUploadRepository.save(fileDB);
    }

}
```

---

**PostServiceImpl.java**

```java
@Service
public class PostServiceImpl implements PostService{

    @Autowired
    private PostRepository postRepository;

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private FileUploadServiceImpl fileUploadService;


    private int count;


    @Override
    public Post createOrUpdatePost(String post, String emailAddress){

        // Removed update code

        Post thePost = new Post();

        try {
            User user = userRepository.findUserByEmailAddress(emailAddress);
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

            thePost = objectMapper.readValue(post, Post.class);
            user.setTotalAds(++count);
            thePost.setPostCreator(user.getFullName());
            thePost.setPostCreatorEmail(emailAddress);
            thePost.setFileUploads(thePost.getFileUploads());
            thePost.setUser(user);
            userRepository.save(user);
            return postRepository.save(thePost);
            // The ad with the same title already exists - go to catch block
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new PostAlreadyExistsException("Post with title " + thePost.getTitle() + " already exists");
        }

    }

}
```

---

**PostController.java** (Only adding the handler method)

```java
    @PostMapping("/create")
    public ResponseEntity<?> createPost(@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file, @Valid @RequestPart String post,  BindingResult result, Principal principal) {
        ResponseEntity<?> errorMap = errorValidationService.validationService(result);
        if(errorMap != null) return errorMap;

        String message = "";
        try {
            fileUploadService.uploadPostImage(file, principal.getName());
            postService.createOrUpdatePost(post, principal.getName());
            message = "Uploaded the file successfully: " + file.getOriginalFilename();

            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(new ApiResponse(message, true));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            message = "Could not upload the file: " + file.getOriginalFilename() + "!";
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body(new ApiResponse(message, false));
        }

    }
```

---

**Postman results**
[image: 400 error]

**Console output**
[image: console output]

**Post DDL MySQL**
[image: Post DDL]

**FileUpload DDL MySQL**
[image: FileUpload DDL]

Comment: Can you try adding getter and setters to all fields in the entities, so we know its not that. JPA supports field based access but you have to put Column annotation to every field

Comment: Hey, forgot to mention I already have getters and setters. I added @Column on each field but getting the same status 400 response :/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add modify your uploadPostImage to this code:

```
@Override
public FileUpload uploadPostImage(MultipartFile file, String emailAddress) throws IOException {
    Post thePost = postRepository.findPostByPostCreatorEmail(emailAddress);

    // new part:
    if (thePost == null) {
        throw new RuntimeException("No post found yet for eMail-Address '" + emailAddress + "' to store images for!");
    }

    String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
    FileUpload fileDB = new FileUpload(++imageCount, fileName, file.getContentType(), emailAddress, file.getBytes(), thePost);

    return fileUploadRepository.save(fileDB);
}
```

Comment: Tried it, still the same error